# No repetir palabras dentro de un bucle en PHP

Tags: php

cada vez que el bucle avanza me trae datos por ejemplo:
luz, luz, oscuridad, sol

dentro de un bucle como puedo hacer para que estas no se repitan?

```
foreach($json as $key => $item)
{
//json se ha procesado para que devuelva palabras
echo $item['palabras'];
}
```

uno
uno dos tres cuatro cuatro cinco seis

Comment: Compartenos tu codigo para poder ayudarte

Comment: revisa http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Aunque una solución es posible, me preguntaría **¿por qué estoy obteniendo datos repetidos?** Si los datos vienen de alguna fuente (base de datos por ejemplo), significa que tienes que refinar tu consulta. No es bueno andar transportando datos repetidos, puede ser costoso. Nadie se lleva 100 personas a Australia para luego escoger a 10. Te puedes arruinar pagando billetes aéreos.

Comment: Podrías ser un poco más especifico en tu pregunta?
Por lo que entiendo intentas generar palabras aleatorias mediente un bucle.  Pregunta:
¿Tienes un array donde almacenas las palabras? O las traes desde alguna base de datos?
Como sea, puedes probar a ir llenando un array con las nuevas palabras que vas recogiendo y utilizar,  y luego consultas con array_search ()   si la palabra ya salió previamente.

Comment: solo necesito saber como hacer que no se repitan en el codigo

Comment: Santy, por favor, muestra el contenido de `$json`, para que puedas obtener una respuesta basada en datos reales.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `array_unique()`

```
$json = array("verde", "rojo", "verde", "azul", "rojo");
$unicos = array_unique($json);
// verde, rojo, azul

foreach($unicos as $key => $item)
{
    echo $item;
}
```

Puedes revisar la documentación aquí: http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php